# Sending bulk of data from one activity to another activity?

Tags: android

Friends i have 2 text boxes...
user have to fill all the text boxes and then press the submit button.
On pressing submit button new activity should start and all the filled information should be displayed over there.
I have tried it using intent but the second activity showing only content of one textbox.
please tell me what to do?
Thanks in advance

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); 

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message2);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    String message2 = editText1.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message2);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

here is my second activity

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

enter code here

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Get the message from the intent

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.

   String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
    textView1.setTextSize(40);
    textView1.setText(message2);
    setContentView(textView1);
    setupActionBar();
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

i am getting text of second text field (message 2) only...

what to do???

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: You need to create a simple example using as few lines of source code as possible to demonstrate your issue.

Comment: either use shared prefrence or send the string using intent.putextra() method....and on the 2nd activity recieve it using bundle

Comment: you are using the same reference name in your first activity like EXTRA_MESSAGE for the two textboxes just rename one textbox like EXTRA_MESSAGE1 and also in second activity. it solved your problem.just refer my answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you have three EditText with id's edt1, edt2, edt3 respectively and a submit button and two activities namely MainActivity where all the three label and a button resides and another activity where there are three TextView with id's txt1, txt2, txt3 respectively, where you have to display the information.

You can send info from one activity to another using intent in the following way:

```
intent.putExtra("Key", "Data");
```

where Key is any string from which you can send the data and data is the info that you are sending. Remember this key is need to receive the data in another activity.

Then in the MainActivity first you need to find the views and then on submit button click listener you need to dos as follows:

```
btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Name", edt1.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("Phone", edt2.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("Age", edt3,getText().toString())
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Then in the AnotherActivity you need to find views for all the TextViews you defined and then to get the data send by MainActivity and set it to textview you need to do as follows:

```
txt1.setText(getIntent.getStringExtra("Name"));
txt2.setText(getIntent.getStringExtra("Phone"));
txt3.setText(getIntent.getStringExtra("Age"));
```

Remember the key must be the same as specified while sending the data. Therefore, declaring them as resource strings or `public static final String` fields of a class is best practice instead of trying to keep them in sync by hand.

Answer (score 4):

Try this to pass the values.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
i.putExtra("Value1", "textbox1");
i.putExtra("Value2", "textbox2"); 
i.putExtra("Value3", "textbox3");
StartActivity(i);
```

Receiving Activity

```
Intent in = getIntent();
String tv1= in.getExtras().getString("Value1");
String tv2= in.getExtras().getString("Value2");
String tv3= in.getExtras().getString("Value3");
```

Answer (score 3):

get the values of textbox and store it to some variables ex, `val1` and `val2` then use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Textbox_val1", val1);
intent.putExtra("Textbox_val2", val2);
startActivity(intent)
```

In the second Activity write

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
if(extras !=null) {
String value1 = extras.getString(Textbox_val1);
String value2 = extras.getString(Textbox_val2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. use `putExtra()` of `Intent`, and use different keys from different textboxes
2. in the other Activity, use `intent.getExtras()`, and retrieve info by your keys

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Intent.putExtra` method to do this.

For example:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "value");
// ... etc
```

And in the `OnResume` or`OnStart` of the target activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("key");
// ... etc
```

See:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

There is an useful way is shared prefernce. Through which you can create,edit, delete data from any activity as well as can fetch data from any of the activity.

To create or edit shared preference from the activity where you want to store data:

```
String share_pref_file = "your_file_name";      
SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences(
        share_pref_time_file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = prefs1.edit();
editor1.putString("your_data", data); //data is your variable
editor1.commit();
```

To fetch data from the activity where you want the data:

```
String share_pref_file = "your_file_name";
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(share_pref_file,
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String strJson = prefs.getString("your_data", "");
```

To delete:

```
String share_pref_file = "your_file_name";
SharedPreferences prefs1 = getSharedPreferences(
            share_pref_file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs1.edit();
    editor.remove(share_pref_file);
    editor.clear();
    editor.commit();
```

Comment: But you must understand the intent of preferences. This are not used for passing data. these are used for storing data.

Comment: But this is a good design to store bulk of data from any of the activity and use it from anywhere the application if it is an activity or not. Intent can only be used for passing the value from one activity two another activity at a time. And Shared prefernce is one of the best way to store data. @M-WaJeEh

Comment: and question owner already used intent it is helpful for him to use another technique. @M-WaJeEh

Answer (score 1):

One of the best way to send bulk of data using ArrayList from one activity to another activity.

Here's one example will send full arraylist data to other activity.

http://prashantandroid.blogspot.in/2013/08/passing-arraylist-from-one-activity-to.html

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple

> Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
>
> i.putExtra("variable_name","variable_value"); startActivity(i);

**It start the second activity and you can find the same data with from bundle**

> Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
>
> if (extras != null){    String value =
> extras.getString("variable_name");   }